# show stdout of background jobs inline

Tags: bash, jobs

Is there an easy way to make the `jobs` command display its `stdout` inline?

I am backgrounding long-running jobs with integer outputs. I need to visually compare those outputs, but they are sent without any context about which job generated which output. This lack of context makes it difficult to differentiate between job results.

Redirecting those outputs to named files would be straightforward, but **I am specifically looking for an easy option to modify the `jobs` output**. My preference (because I am lazy) would be to enter something like `jobs --stdout' and have it display outputs after the default job details:

```
[1]   Done                    zcat a.gz | grep ^@ | wc -l  Output1
[2]   Done                    zcat a.gz | grep ^+ | wc -l  Output2
[3]-  Done                    zcat b.gz | grep ^@ | wc -l  Output3
[4]+  Done                    zcat b.gz | grep ^+ | wc -l  Output4
```

A well-informed and definitive "No" is an acceptable answer to this question;  context for that 'no" will be greatly appreciated. I've searched `man jobs`, but that manpage is enormous and I may have missed something.

Thanks for sharing your time and experience!

Chris

Comment: All your background jobs have the same stdout -- your terminal. In order for the shell to be able to distinguish between their outputs either a) their output should be formatted differently or b) it should be sent to different file descriptors. Neither a) and b) is an easily available option, both need work and will run into a lot of issues. Anyways, the format of your `jobs --stdout` would not work for jobs with _copious_ output. BTW, on many systems you can replace your `zcat | grep | wc` pipelines with eg `zgrep -c ^@ a.gz`.

Comment: Redirect the output of each job to a different file.   e.g. `zcat a.gz | grep ^@ | wc -l > output.1 &`  and `zcat a.gz | grep ^+ | wc -l  > output.2 &`, etc.   if you do this a lot you could write a shell function or script to automatically construct an output filename (e.g. based on tty, timestamp, and/or other factors), and then run "$@" in the background, redirecting all output to the output file.  Optionally, it could insert a comment with the command-line as the first line of output.  There'd more to it than that, of course, but that's the basic outline.